# How do I turn off this jQuery plugin? (snappish)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

So i'm working with this plugin http://code.pb.io/jquery-snappish/

and initialising it with

```
$('#wrapper').snappish();
```

The problem is that I only want this functionality on the home page. How would I go about turning it off after the user has navigated to another page?

Currently the pages are being loaded via AJAX calls firing off of nav clicks.

Comment: instead of calling the plugin for the global wrapper element why can't you initialize it for an wrapper element which is present only in the home page - you will have to do it after the ajax request which loads the page

Comment: I looked at the source code, it doesn't look like it has an option to turn itself off once initialized. So if you can't do what @ArunPJohny suggested, you'll have to read the code and undo its event bindings in your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you added a conditional? For example, if your `body` tag had a class of `homepage` you could do the following.

```
if ($('body').hasClass('homepage')) {
    $('#wrapper').snappish();
} 
else {
    /* your logic here */
};
```